# Create databsse with php

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am trying to create a mysql database using php. here is the code:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "XXXXXXXX";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE myDB";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Database created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

here is the error:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/XXXXXXX/public_html/phpinfo.php on line 10
>       Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

any ideas?

Comment: I wish it were that easy

Comment: The code works for me. I've only changed password.

Answer (score 0):

follow this steps :-

**Step # 1** : Stop mysql service

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

**Step # 2**: Start to MySQL server w/o password:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

**Step # 3**: Connect to mysql server using mysql client:

```
mysql -u root
```

**Step # 4**: Setup new MySQL root user password
mysql> `use mysql;`

mysql>

```
update user set password=PASSWORD("NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD") where User='root';
```

mysql>

```
flush privileges;
```

mysql> `quit`

**Step # 5**: Stop MySQL Server:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

**Step # 6**: Start MySQL server and test it

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start

mysql -u root -pNEW-ROOT-PASSWORD
```